# Randomly Permuting a List of List with No Repetition

Tags: python, list

I have a list of the same lists of number. I would like to randomly permute each row so that there is no repetition in the columns. Maybe keep permuting the rows until all the repetitions are eliminated is a way but there should be a better way.

For example,

```
input = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    ]

output = [
    [2, 1, 4, 3],
    [1, 3, 2, 4],
    [4, 2, 3, 1],
    ]

no_good = [
    [1, 3, 2 ,4],
    [3, 1, 4, 2],
    [3, 4, 2, 1]
]
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried to solve it

Comment: Sounds like a homework question that you want us to solve for you. Show us what you've done and you can get help from there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I really have no clue at all (I got no training in programming).

Comment: I am thinking about keep permuting each row until there is no repetition. But there may be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach, using [`shuffle`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-random-sample-function/), which will take a list of numbers and will permute it in order to create a 2 dimensional list:

```
import random

inList = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4]]

def createMatrix(inList,n):
    firstRow = random.sample(inList,4)
    permutes = random.sample(inList,4)
    return list(firstRow[i:]+firstRow[:i] for i in permutes[:n])

outList = createMatrix([1,2,3,4],3)
for elem in outList:
    print(elem)
```

One of the possible results of the above, without same numbers in the same column, would be this:

```
[2, 1, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you! I realize that it is not completely random in the sense that the relative order is preserved in each row but this is already good enough to serve my original purpose. Thank you!